# Using Enthought Canopy over SSH+Putty Fails to Start

Tags: ssh, x11, putty, enthought

I have Enthought Canopy installed on a machine running RedHat Enterprise Linux 5. I installed it successfully and can verify it runs.

I would like to be able to use it remotely from a windows computer, I have installed putty + xming for X11 forwarding. I can use regular applications like gedit and firefox fine. However when I try using canopy by launching ~/Canopy/canopy an empty gray box for the welcome screen appears, disappears after a few moments, and canopy exits with no return error without having started.

When I ssh with X forwarding from another linux computer, I can use canopy just fine.

There is no error code, I don't see any debug flags and I can't find any log files. I really have no idea why I cant access canopy with putty and xming.

I am trying this as a solution for interns so they can use a machine with access to our datafiles from their windows computers.

I highly appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Curiously using MobaXterm (http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) seems to work fine.. it sets the display using it's own X11 scheme seperate from xming.. this is all odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canopy needs some features not provided by XMing and a few other X server implementation on windows. See the following article for more details:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/21873380-Running-Canopy-Linux-via-remote-display-VNC-remote-X-display-

In short, use MobaXterm ( http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ ) or VcXSrv ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/ )

EDIT: newer versions of Canopy have fixed this bug and should work fine with XMing

Comment: Ah, thanks for linking that web page.

Additionally, it seems Canopy can also work through Cygwin/X which is what I will stick with. 

Thanks!